# How can I add a silent pause for a few seconds using punctuation with Baidu's speech synthesis (tts)?

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, baidu

How can I add a silent pause for a few seconds using punctuation with Baidu's speech synthesis (tts)?

Three periods adds a bit of a pause, as does a comma, but adding six periods or more commas doesn't seem to add more silence.

I'm using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/baidu-speech-synthesizer

Here is some sample code:

```
let chinese = bss.speak(`你好... 你好`, options)
```

The following has the same amount of pausing as the code above:

```
let chinese = bss.speak(`你好...,...,...,... 你好`, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting spaces between periods or commas. (Just a guess based on my limited use of the MS speech-to-text process.)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add a pause to your speech by inputting characters directly into your string, add '/ / / / /'. If you want a longer pause, try adding more '/'.